# Migrating from H2 embedded database to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, h2, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

I've been using the embedded H2 database with SonarQube 5.1 for a while but am now looking to migrate to a PostgreSQl db, can you advise me on how to do this?

My only worry is that the 'ignore issue' feature will not be ported when moving to the new db, is there any way I can avoid this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning in the footer states quite clearly, you *cannot* migrate the H2 database. That's *why* there's a big red warning in the footer when you're using the embedded database. It's for initial evaluation purposes only.

Comment: In that case, how can I go about changing the database from H2 to PostgreSQL without migrating the data?

Comment: Simply edit $SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties to point to the new DB

Comment: As per the screenshot given on their [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/db-copy/), SonarQube DB Copy Tool can be used to migrate from H2 DB. But it is commercial.

Answer (score 0):

For docker containers and mounting to an external filesystem for sonarqube, there is no sonar.properties except in the docker container.  There are environment properties SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME, SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD, and SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL.  However, in the docker compose .yml file, even with those properties, sonarqube new installation (9.9) still defaults only to using h2 internally.  I see that sonar has indeed created the sonar user into the postgresql database. But, the view from sonarcube UI in the admin/management section, still says the database in use is h2.   I'm missing something but I don't know what, yet. (I attempted migration from sonarqube 6.7.4 to 7.9.2-community but that failed due to a plugin mismatch for which I decided to just take everything to new as the old data/analysis can be disarded. Note that in our configuration for sonarqube 6.7.4 we did not modify the in-container sonar.properties and it talked to the postgresql database fine.  Now doing a clean install of v9 and hitting this issue.  It's interesting there are no clear docs I've found yet on how to change.)

In version 9x
Database H2 
Database Version 2.1.214 (2022-06-13) 
Username 
URL jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar 
Driver H2 JDBC Driver 
Driver Version 2.1.214 (2022-06-13) 
Default transaction isolation TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

In version 6.7.4 (which does not have a customized sonar.properties)
Database    PostgreSQL 
Database Version    10.1 
Username    redacted 
URL jdbc:postgresql://sonar_postgresql/sonar 
Driver  PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 
Driver Version  42.2.1

Update: just found this LOL - https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-9-8-is-upgraded-to-sonarqube-9-9-and-after-upgrade-there-are-no-projects-visible/86198/7

Sonar decided to change their environment variable names from SONARQUBE_JDBC to SONAR_JDBC.  With that update it works to find postgres.  However, at a restart of the container, the admin password change is lost, hopefully just as we are now pointing to postgres and no longer h2.  https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/release-upgrade-notes/#release-9.9-upgrade-notes